# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'OSGI-OPT/src/org/kohsuke/args4j/spi/URLOptionHandler.java'

Tags: java, android, google-closure-compiler

when adding com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:v20171023  and running my Android project i got this error

More than one file was found with OS independent path 'OSGI-OPT/src/org/kohsuke/args4j/spi/URLOptionHandler.java'

Could you please help me to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Try using the unshaded version. It does not include the dependencies: https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A"closure-compiler-unshaded"